# Cargar página maquetada html ionic

Tags: html5, ionic, angular, typescript, ionic3

mediante un Provider he creado un array de elementos:

```
this.arrLista = [
                  {
                    titulo: 'Pagina 1',
                    ruta: 'templates/paginaUno.html',
                    icono: 'assets/imgs/imagenUno.jpeg'
                  },
                  {
                   titulo: 'Pagina 2
                   ruta: 'templates/pagDos.html',
                   icono: 'assets/imgs/imgDos
                 }, 
                 {
                   titulo: 'Pagina 3
                   ruta: 'templates/pagTres.html',
                   icono: 'assets/imgs/imgTres.jpeg'
                 }
                 ]
```

Siendo:

- titulo: el titulo a buscar
- ruta: donde tengo en mi proyecto el archivo físico
- icono: la imagen a mostrar en la Lista

El cual es llamado mediante un searchBar y localizado por el arrLista.titulo.
Me gustaría que mediante un onclick al elemento me abriera en una vista el contenido del html y cuya ruta de acceso está almacenado en arrLista.ruta.

Es posible? Qué puedo hacer?
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Es posible y es relativamente sencillo:

Mediante AJAX obtienes el html:

```
text: string;

onClick(ruta: string) {

    this.httpClient.get(ruta, { responseType: 'text' })
            .subscribe(data => this.text = data);
}
```

Y ese texto lo muestras así:

```
<div [innerHTML]="text"></div>
```

### Nota:

Esta solución funciona usando Angular en una aplicación web, al ser Ionic los *assets* posiblemente puedan ser accedidos de otro modo, sin requerir una llamada AJAX, ya que deberían estar como parte de la aplicación en el dispositivo móvil.

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar el componente "modal" de semantic-ui, que es como boostrap, sólo que usa jquey para sus componentes.

y con (click) le pasas una función que dispare el modal.

pasa en la función la url

semantic también tiene un panel lateral.

espero te sirva